# logstash pattern to use to filter my log data

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-file

I am new to ELK stack and grok filter.

Want help regarding a logstash conf file to display the data in kibana (pie chart)

my logfile is available in the location C:\ELK\Test\reviewoutput.log

```
wf_review1 FAILED
wf_review2 PASS
wf_review3 PASS
wf_review4 PASS
wf_review5 FAILED
```

and here is my conf file

```
input{
file{
path=>"C:/ELK/Test/codereview.log"
}
}
filter{
grok{
match=>{"message"=>"%{WORD:workflow} %{WORD:status}"}
}
}
#output{
#elasticsearch{
#hosts=>["localhost"]
#index=>"logstash-*"
#}
output{stdout{codec=>rubydebug}
}
```

The above code is not echoing the parsed log into console. if I change the input type to "stdin" and pass the value in console, it echoes the log into stdout/console. Not sure what I am missing here.

I am just trying to filter the above log data to look for the keyword PASS or FAILED and pump the filtered data into elasticsearch. Later in the kibana dashboard I want to display the no of success and failures(PASS/FAILED) of the workflows in a pie chart.

I am running ELK stack on windows machine.

your help/suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by adding the below line inside my file filter.

```
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"

input{
    file{
        path => "C:/ELK/Test/codereview.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
```

These two links actually helped me after many hours of searching for a solution :)
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/reading-a-log-file-into-logstash/24514 
https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3115

But still, with the above logic it's not reading the last line of the logfile.(You need to press the enter after the last line to read the complete log entries)but I am not sure why it doesn't read the last log entry as it is!?